# Printing an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, reverse

Is there a way of printing arrays in C++?

I'm trying to make a function that reverses a user-input array and then prints it out. I tried Googling this problem and it seemed like C++ can't print arrays. That can't be true can it?

Comment: The question itself is a bit flawed, tbh. Have you thought of what it even means to "print an array"? What is the data type on the array (number, string, user-defined, etc.)? How should the data be displayed? Do you need commas in the number? Do you want scientific notation? Should each element be on a separate line or do you want to distribute them in columns? Should columns be fixed width or dynamic?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just iterate over the elements. Like this:

```
for (int i = numElements - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    cout << array[i];
```

Note: As Maxim Egorushkin pointed out, this could overflow. See his comment below for a better solution.

Comment: I'd also like to note, that in C++ world you mostly don't create a new, reversed array and then print it.  Instead, you usually iterate the array in the other way: for (i = numElements-1; i>=0; i--)  cout << array[i] << ",";

Comment: You forgot to declare the i as an integer didn' you? That's what I did (well not really since I was supposed to reverse it).. so doing something like "for (int i = staerd-1; i >= 0; i--)" is the best way?

Comment: This version might overflow `int`, since the number of elements is `size_t`. Robust version is even more elegant: `for(size_t i = numElements; i--;)`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I see your point, your solution seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: for(auto x: someArray){cout<<x<<endl;};

Comment: @Martian2049 Not equivalent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you please elaborate on your comment?  Why is MartianMartian's solution not equivalent?  Do you recommend against this solution?  Why?

Answer (score 50):

Use the STL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>    userInput;


    // Read until end of input.
    // Hit control D  
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(userInput)
             );

    // ITs 2021 now move this up as probably the best way to do it.
    // Range based for is now "probably" the best alternative C++20
    // As we have all the range based extension being added to the language
    for(auto const& value: userInput)
    {
        std::cout << value << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print the array in reverse using the range based stuff
    for(auto const& value: userInput | std::views::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << value << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";


    // Print in Normal order
    std::copy(userInput.begin(),
              userInput.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",")
             );
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print in reverse order:
    std::copy(userInput.rbegin(),
              userInput.rend(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",")
             );
    std::cout << "\n";

}
```

Comment: this I just ran this on gcc 4.6.1 using g++..it does not work

Comment: Just wondering whether there is any speed advantage with this approach?

Comment: @SamStoelinga: In speed terms. Always measure. I would use this for readability (thus maintainability). But iterators on vectors have always been considered very efficient so its not a worry I would really consider in most situations (unless speed was critical).

Answer (score 37):

May I suggest using the fish bone operator?

```
for (auto x = std::end(a); x != std::begin(a); )
{
    std::cout <<*--x<< ' ';
}
```

(Can you spot it?)

Answer (score 14):

Besides the for-loop based solutions, you can also use an [ostream_iterator<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).  Here's an example that leverages the sample code in the (now retired) SGI STL reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  short foo[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

  using namespace std;
  copy(foo,
       foo + sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]),
       ostream_iterator<short>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

This generates the following:

```
 ./a.out 
1
3
5
7
```

However, this may be overkill for your needs.  A straight for-loop is probably all that you need, although [litb's template sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370354/69998) is quite nice, too.

**Edit**: Forgot the "printing in reverse" requirement.  Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  short foo[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

  using namespace std;

  reverse_iterator<short *> begin(foo + sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]));
  reverse_iterator<short *> end(foo);

  copy(begin,
       end,
       ostream_iterator<short>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

and the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
7
5
3
1
```

**Edit**: C++14 update that simplifies the above code snippets using array iterator functions like [std::begin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::rbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    short foo[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

    // Generate array iterators using C++14 std::{r}begin()
    // and std::{r}end().

    // Forward
    std::copy(std::begin(foo),
              std::end(foo),
              std::ostream_iterator<short>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // Reverse
    std::copy(std::rbegin(foo),
              std::rend(foo),
              std::ostream_iterator<short>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are *declared arrays* and arrays that are *not* declared, but otherwise created, particularly using `new`:

```
int *p = new int[3];
```

That array with 3 elements is created dynamically (and that `3` could have been calculated at runtime, too), and a pointer to it which has the size erased from its type is assigned to `p`. You cannot get the size anymore to print that array. A function that only receives the pointer to it can thus not print that array.

Printing declared arrays is easy. You can use `sizeof` to get their size and pass that size along to the function including a pointer to that array's elements. But you can also create a template that accepts the array, and deduces its size from its declared type:

```
template<typename Type, int Size>
void print(Type const(& array)[Size]) {
  for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

The problem with this is that it won't accept pointers (obviously). The easiest solution, I think, is to use `std::vector`. It is a dynamic, resizable "array" (with the semantics you would expect from a real one), which has a `size` member function:

```
void print(std::vector<int> const &v) {
  std::vector<int>::size_type i;
  for(i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

You can, of course, also make this a template to accept vectors of other types.

Comment: What, no std::copy_n to an ostream_iterator? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Most of the libraries commonly used in C++ can't print arrays, per se. You'll have to loop through it manually and print out each value.

Printing arrays and dumping many different kinds of objects is a feature of higher level languages.

Comment: You can do it one statement in C++. I don't see this as a missing feature as using iterators makes it so much more powerful. Now I can abstract away where I am printing: it does not matter if the destination is console, pipe, file, another container, a function, a DB. It all looks and behaves the same.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is! You'll have to loop through the array and print out each item individually.

Comment: standard algorithms dont require a loop. (though thay may use one internally).

Comment: What if I don't have access to the STL?

Comment: Then you aren't using C++. Perhaps you're using Symbian/C++, or some subset of C++ provided by an embedded compiler. (Granted that technically, the STL is a precursor to the standard libraries in standard C++. But usually when people say "STL", they mean "the class and function templates in the C++ standard libraries", not the pre-standard STL. Hence STL is a subset of C++).

Comment: @Steve _"Then you aren't using C++"_ Not necessarily so. A freestanding implementation is explicitly permitted to omit all but a small collection of standard headers, and none of those mandated contains functionality inherited from the STL. [Further reading](http://eel.is/c++draft/compliance)

Answer (score 1):

This might help
//Printing The Array

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{cout << numbers[i];}
```

n is the size of the array

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::string ss[] = { "qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvb" };
for ( auto el : ss ) std::cout << el << '\n';
```

Works basically like foreach.

Answer (score 0):

My simple answer is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int data[]{ 1, 2, 7 };
    for (int i = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << data[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explaining your code, and how it responds to the question,  would greatly increase the quality of this answer.

Comment: The code is self-explanatory it reverses an array and print it as elements

Comment: the output is 721

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse iterators to print an array in reverse:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (auto it = std::rbegin(x); it != std::rend(x); ++it) 
        std::cout << *it;
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/MGdr66Ksz)

```
54321
```

If you already reversed the array, you can replace `std::rbegin` and `std::rend` with `std::begin`/`std::end`, respectively, to iterate the array in forward direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward to copy the array's elements to a suitable output iterator.  For example (using C++20 for the Ranges version):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& print_array(std::ostream& os, std::array<T,N> const& arr)
{
    std::ranges::copy(arr, std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
    return os;
}
```

Quick demo:

```
int main()
{
    std::array example{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", };
    print_array(std::cout, example) << '\n';
}
```

Of course it's more useful if we can output any kind of collection, not only arrays:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <ranges>

template<std::ranges::input_range R>
std::ostream& print_array(std::ostream& os, R const& arr)
{
    using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>;
    std::ranges::copy(arr, std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
    return os;
}
```

The question mentions reversing the array for printing.  That's easily achieved by using a *view adapter*:

```
    print_array(std::cout, example | std::views::reverse) << '\n';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// Just do this, use a vector with this code and you're good lol -Daniel

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    std::vector<const char*> arry = { "Item 0","Item 1","Item 2","Item 3" ,"Item 4","Yay we at the end of the array"};
    
    if (arry.size() != arry.size() || arry.empty()) {
        printf("what happened to the array lol\n ");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arry.size(); i++)
    {   
        if (arry.max_size() == true) {
            cout << "Max size of array reached!";
        }
        cout << "Array Value " << i << " = " << arry.at(i) << endl;
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Could tou give more details with your code, some explanation will be welcome ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<Windows.h>` is not a standard C++ header.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to make a function that prints every single element in an array;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4, 77, 88};

void coutArr(int *arr, int size){
   for(int i=0; i<size/4; i++){
      cout << arr[i] << endl;
   }
}

int main(){
   coutArr(myArray, sizeof(myArray));
}
```

The function above prints every single element in an array **only, not commas etc.**

You may be wondering "Why sizeoff(arr) divided by 4?". It's because cpp prints 4 if there's only a single element in an array.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry! I was too careless. I should've put an asterisk before the "arr" argument. It worked now.

Comment: Now it always prints 3 elements, regardless of the array size: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qWfcYr5sx

Comment: I've came up with an update, turns out the size of an array must be specified outside of the function. Else, the function will reuse the inside-function-stored-previously variable.

Comment: This is better, but you should divide by `sizeof(int)`, not 4.

Comment: you should use `std::size` not `sizeof`.