# A working std::copy example - printing an array

Tags: c++, arrays, std

This does not work.  I'm trying to learn how to use std::copy but I can't find any working code.
I ran this in gcc 4.6.1. And it does not do anything when I hit control D.  If I hit Control C...it prints out the new lines only.

Found code here:

[Printing an array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370323/printing-an-array-in-c)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iterator> 

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<int>    userInput; 

    // Read until end of input. 
    // Hit control D   
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
              std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
              std::back_inserter(userInput) 
             ); 

    // Print in Normal order 
    std::copy(userInput.begin(), 
              userInput.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",") 
             ); 
    std::cout << "\n"; 

    // Print in reverse order: 
    std::copy(userInput.rbegin(), 
              userInput.rend(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",") 
             ); 
    std::cout << "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: The ^D may not be visible to your program until you also hit enter. It may need to be on a line by itself.

Comment: The code is fine. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? Then the end of stream marker is generated with <ctrl>-Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you're running it or what you're entering but that seems to run fine for me:

```
pax$ g++ -o qq qq.cpp ; ./qq
1
2
3
4
5
0
9
8
7
6
<CTRL-D>
1,2,3,4,5,0,9,8,7,6,
6,7,8,9,0,5,4,3,2,1,
```

This is with gcc 4.3.4 under Cygwin. One thing to watch out for is that (in my environment at least), `CTRL-D` has to be entered on a new line. Entering:

```
1 2 3 4 5<CTRL-D>
```

didn't work for me (the `CTRL-D` was ignored) but:

```
1 2 3 4 5
<CTRL-D>
```

did.

You can bypass those issues with `CTRL-D` by doing something like:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 | ./qq
```

so that end of file does not depend on your terminal characteristics. This is especially important since it *may* be that MinGW (being a Windows application rather than running under CygWin's emulation layer) requires the Windows end-of-file character, `CTRL-Z`.

Running this command acts as expected:

```
pax$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 | ./qq
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,
0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,
```