# Reading space separated input into an array in C++

Tags: c++

What is the easiest way to read space separated input into an array?

```
//input:5
        1 2 3 4 7



int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int array[n];
    for (int i =0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    cout<<array; 
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the code above but the output is 0x7ffe42b757b0.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. It's the most useless description of the problem.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. What actually happens? Does it crash? Does it read everything into the first element of the array? Something else?

Comment: On the other note, I noticed the problem (_I think_). Variable length arrays are not standard C++. Consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Wild guess: You are confused by the output and put the blame on the wrong piece. `cout << array` doesn't do what you probably want it to.

Comment: And is the input always it? or can it be anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing an array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370323/printing-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies with your printing. Since `array` is a pointer, you are only printing an address value.

Instead, do this:

```
for (int i =0;i<n;i++){
    cout<< array[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.That's the problem.I have had many problems like this since I changed to C++ from Python.

Comment: @J.Ren. C++ has many features to offer that prevent you from having to use fixed size arrays. In my example you can put an input string of any size.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by passing `std::istream_iterator` to `std::vector` constructor:

```
std::vector<int> v{
    std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, 
    std::istream_iterator<int>{}
    };
```

[`std::vector` has a constructor that accepts 2 iterators to the input range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

[`istream_iterator<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is an iterator that reads `int` from a `std::istream`.

A drawback of this approach is that one cannot set the maximum size of the resulting array. And that it reads the stream till its end.

---

If you need to read a fixed number of elements, then something like the following would do:

```
int arr[5]; // Need to read 5 elements.
for(auto& x : arr)
    if(!(std::cin >> x))
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to parse an int");
```

Comment: This is a cool construction, can you explain what it does exactly?

Comment: @Chiel Added references for you.

Comment: I don't manage to run this. If I put this in my example, it never stops asking for input.

Comment: Your example does not work with clang. It never ends the cin

Comment: @Chiel Use [std::copy_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n), see [this article](https://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/cpp-competitive-programming-io/).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Can you make the example work and write it as a working test like the code you linked before?

Answer (score 1):

array variable always give base address of an array

```
for (int i =0;i<n;i++){
    cout<< array[i] << " ";
    cout<<*(array+i)<< " ";
}
```

Both cout statements will print same only.
in short
array[i] compiler will internally convert into *(array+i) like this only

in the second cout statement from base address of an array it won't add value,since it is an pointer it will add sizeof(int) each time for an increment

Comment: @O'Neil you are correct!.i knew it but missed it . thanks for identifying that mistake