# How do i print an array using iostream?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, ostream

```
    virtual ostream &put(ostream &os){
        return A::put(os)<<f()<<"/min   "<<len<< "  "<<*values;
    }
```

Is there a way to see print the entire array "values"?
Each time i execute the program it prints the first lement in the array,is there a way to print each values in a row?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370323/printing-an-array-in-c

Comment: It's an extremely basic question involving looping on arrays/lists, I highly suggest you to take a look at some beginners tutorials.

Comment: I recommend a `for` loop and operator `%`.