# How to get a class to cout as one of its array properties

Tags: c++, class, cout

I'm brand new to C++ (my usual language is Python).

I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370341/5049813) how to print an array. I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981858/5049813) how to get a class object to `cout` as one of its properties. And I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224977/5049813) that the `cout` only works if it can access the class's property as a `friend`.

But, when I combine the answers, it doesn't seem to work.
Here's what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TicTacToeGame {
    int board[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, TicTacToeGame const &m);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, TicTacToeGame const &m) {
    for (int i = 0; i++; i < 9) {
        os << m.board[i];
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    TicTacToeGame game;
    cout << game;
    return 0;
}
```

And nothing prints on the screen.

What I'd like to see is something along the lines of `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, but fancy formatting isn't needed as long as I can see the array.

How can I get that to happen?

Comment: You should output a newline or `endl` after `cout << game`

Comment: @M.M why should I do that?

Comment: Standard output is line-buffered by default so any partial line may never appear on your screen; it depends on the OS and calling environment

Comment: It looks like my answer does that (accidentally) already. Thank you for letting me know that I should keep it like that.

Comment: You need to have at least one more warning enabled: my compile of your code generates: "warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]"

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I'm coding in Atom and using a compiler under the hood so I'm not seeing any of those warnings. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i++; i < 9) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [@immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50478809/5049813) for reminding me how to do for loops again. (I haven't had to do those in so long...)

Here's the fancier version of the operator function that I decided to go with for the time being, so that it prints out like a tic-tac-toe board.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, TicTacToeGame const &m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        os << m.board[i];
        if (i%3!=2) {
            os << " ";
        }
        if (((i+1) % 3) == 0) {
            os << "\n";
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```