# Why does this merge sort code keeps giving me this weird output?

Tags: c++, mergesort

I wrote the count sort code but it is showing me weird output, can you tell where I am wrong ??

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void CountSort(int a[], int n, int k)
{
    int count[k + 1]={0};
    int b[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ++count[a[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        b[count[a[i]]-1] = a[i];
        --count[a[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 8, 7, 7, 9, 2, 0, 1, 9};
    CountSort(a, 17, 9);
    cout<<"The sorted array is  ->  "<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives output like this -

```
The sorted array is  ->  0x7bfdd0
```

[ScreenShot of the code and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEPJx.png)

Comment: who told you `cout << a;` would be the way to print elements of an array?

Comment: There is no universally accepted "correct way" to print the contents of an array. 
 See [Printing an array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370323/printing-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Side note: `int b[n]` is a Variable Length Array, which is not valid C++. It may be supported as a non-standard extension on some compilers, but you should unlearn it. Also `using namespace std` and include bits/stdc++.h are considered things you should avoid.

Comment: Why title says "merge sort" and code says "CountSort" (this is invalid implementation of count sort)? Do you know what are you suppose to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have two fault.

1. print array method is wrong.
2. third loop is wrong in `CountSort`. this loop working only once.

There is fix result.

```
void CountSort(int a[], int n, int k)
{
    int count[k + 1]={0};
    int b[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ++count[a[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[count[a[i]]-1] = a[i];
        --count[a[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 8, 7, 7, 9, 2, 0, 1, 9};
    CountSort(a, 17, 9);
    cout<<"The sorted array is  ->  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
The sorted array is  ->  0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 4 5 7 7 8 9 9
```

Answer (score 2):

When trying to print the array, you cannot just use `std::cout << a`. At the moment your code is printing the memory address of the array `a`, which is not what you want.

To fix the problem, print all elements of the array, one by one. These loops can be helpful:

```
for (const auto& elem : a)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); i++)
    std::cout << a[i] << " ";
```