# How to display reversed values in array using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning C++ by myself through Udemy courses, and now thanks to some good advice I'm using a book "C++ Primer".

I will show you one of my codes. Please give me any advice on my route to programming, and why it does not work. It does not show the values in reversed manner using pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

 
void reverse_array (int *arr, int size)
{
    int *start = arr;  
    int *end = arr + size -1;

    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start ++;
        end --;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int arr [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);

    reverse_array (arr,size);

    cout << reverse_array << endl;
}
```

Comment: `cout << reverse_array << endl;` [Printing an array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1370323) Also, you should print the array, not the function.

Comment: Also, you have an extraneous `int main () {` at the start of the program.

Comment: Change `int size = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);` to `auto size{ std::size(arr) };`

Comment: `void reverse_array (int *arr, int size)` returns nothing, so even once you get the call sorted out, still can't print the result.

Comment: Why is every second line in your code empty that makes the code involving the vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Deleted the { at the beginnig -- should not be there, when it comes to other suggestions mentioned, it still does not show the proper results

Comment: Should  I squeeze my code without empty lines , make it more tight?

Comment: @Alex87 -- Programmers are trained to read a line of code, and then expect that the next line of code is on...the next line, not double or tripled spaced away from the current line.  The one main exception is when function bodies or class/struct definitions are separated.

Comment: @Alex87 The code basically works. You're just not printing the array correctly. https://godbolt.org/z/efYYdb1oj

Comment: @user4581301 the function modifies the array inline, it doesn't need to return a result.

Comment: Thank you so much for all tips and comments!!!

Comment: The function doesn't need to return a result, but `<<` still expects a returned result. There are two choices: Call the function and then print the array or change the return type to something `<<` knows how to print. First option is easier than second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answers for your code problems.
In your code, when you use [cout <<"reverse Array" << endl], you are trying to print the address of reverse_array function instead of printing the function has been reversed. To print index in an array, you have to use a "for-loop" and print every single index.

When calling the reverse_array function, you pass only the arr and size arguments without the & sign to indicate the address of the array. Therefore, in the reverse_array function, the arr parameter is copied and changing the value of arr does not affect the array in the main function. To invert the array in the desired way, you need to pass the address of the array using &arr[0] or arr.